# Why constant variables for selecting DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there a reason as to why we declare the variables as constant while selecting elements from the DOM? I see a lot of devlopers and tutorials use

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
```

Comment: Closed as a false positive. The specific focus of the question merits more attention. Voted to re-open.

Comment: Hello, the question is misleading anyway, because it makes an assumption that when you select an element from the DOM, it's better to use const. I think this is great that it's pointed to the right question asking the difference between const and let, keeping close.

Answer (score 1):

You want to store the result so you do not have to query it again. And it is also best practice to use `const` as often as you can so you cannot accidentally reasign it. In case you DO need to reasign it, it is preferable to use `let`.